# Change the result of SQL query by PIVOT

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I am going to change the model of result in SQL query.
Imagine the query below:

```
SELECT
    es.LatinName,
    es.CreatedOn
FROM Salex.ExportFile ef
INNER JOIN Salex.ExportFileStep efs ON efs.ExportFileId = ef.Id
INNER JOIN GeneralSalex.ExportSubject es ON es.Id = efs.ExportSubjectId
WHERE ef.Id = 38
```

The result is somthing below:
[image]

But I want to place LatinName values in Columns and its CreatedOn values are their below (Expected result in one row):

```
|Packing List               | Export Bill Of Lading      | ...
|2021-06-15 16:12:57.6200000| 2021-07-31 09:30:12.5600000| ...
```

I tried to use `PIVOT` like the code below but I couldn't expexted result:

```
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days,   
  [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]    
FROM  
(
    SELECT
        es.LatinName,
        es.CreatedOn
    FROM Salex.ExportFile ef
    INNER JOIN Salex.ExportFileStep efs ON efs.ExportFileId = ef.Id
    INNER JOIN GeneralSalex.ExportSubject es ON es.Id = efs.ExportSubjectId
    WHERE ef.Id = 38
    ) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  AVG(CreatedOn)  
  FOR LatinName IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors, but do include sample data and your expected results as consumable text. Are your 9 distinct values fixed or does this need to be dynamic?

Comment: None of the values in `LatinName` have the value `0`, `1`, etc so you aren't going to get any data back.

Comment: Though, in truth, this is really a task for your presentation layer., not the SQL Layer.

Comment: @Stu The latin names are static. But CreatedOn values are dynamic by changing ef.Id

Comment: @ThomA What changes should I apply to work?

Comment: Use the *actual* names. Have you had a look at the documentation for the operator?

Comment: @ThomA Would you pleas alter the code? I couldn't understand your mean

Comment: No, as I can't run it to test afterwards; you've not fixed the images as yet. Why are you unable to replace the numbers with the words yourself?

Comment: @ThomA Image is the result of my first query. How should I fix it?

Comment: As I stated *"replace the numbers with the words"*

Comment: @ThomA LatinNames are string not number

Comment: I know, so why are *you* stating that they are in your code...?

Comment: This is my tried code. It is incorrect. If it is misleading I can remove it

Comment: And again, why in your code are you trying to pivot on the **Latin Word** `0`? None of your "Latin words" have the value `0` in your image.

Answer (score 0):

It would be somthing like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT es.LatinName, es.CreatedOn
    FROM Salex.ExportFile ef
    INNER JOIN Salex.ExportFileStep efs ON efs.ExportFileId = ef.Id
    INNER JOIN GeneralSalex.ExportSubject es ON es.Id = efs.ExportSubjectId
    WHERE ef.Id = 38
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(CreatedOn)
    FOR LatinName IN (
        [Packing List], [Export Bill Of Lading], [Insurance],
        [Provide Export Warranty], [Custom Declaration],
        [Inventory Permit], [Export Invoice], [Sale Invoice],
        [Issued Certificate]
    )
) AS PivotTable;
```